# Height of a div isn't expanding

Tags: javascript, html, css

HTML

```
<div id = "four">
    <div id = "photos">
         <ul>
            <li onclick="preview('pic1')" id = "pic1">
                  <img src = "img.png">
            </li>

         </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
#four
{
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: rgb(213,213,119);
}

#photos{
position: relative;
width: 100%;
display: block;
top: 0;
 }
 #photos ul li{
 position: relative;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 float: left;
 width: 18vw;
 height: 18vw;
 margin: 1.03vw;
 overflow: hidden;
 background: black;
 }

 #photos ul li > img{
position: relative;
bottom: 10px;
/*-webkit-background-size: cover center center; 
-moz-background-size: cover; 
-o-background-size: cover; 
background-size: cover center center;*/
width: 140%;
}
```

For some reason they display like they are all positioned absolutely on 0px height #four #photos ul. Like I cant change the background and or the hidden overflow. Not sure whats up.

Comment: you are not declaring any css for the uls, could be they are collapsing or something? Try to inspect the elements with the browser, firebug or chrome inspector, you will notice there whats going on, also think declaring position could be the cause

Comment: change "height: 18vw;" to "height: 18vh;" and see if that works

Comment: @Fabio I plan on having more than a few pics. about 20 li or something like that. Even with min-height :/

Comment: it doesn't matter, what I mean is you have vw (which is a WIDTH variable) in a height declaration, so I think that is where the problem is. try changing it to vh, or vm, or rem or % or px or whatever but vw, and then adjust to your needs

Answer (score 0):

Use reset css and give clearfix to the `ul`.

This should solve your problem of height 0px for #four #photos ul.

HTML

```
<ul class="clearfix">
```

CSS

```
    /*limited reset*/
html, body, div, section, article, aside, header, hgroup, footer, nav, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, address, time, span, em, strong, img, ol, ul, li, figure, canvas, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/karan3112/sb66160L/)